# O resultado é sempre o mesmo, como se as condições fossem iguais

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div>
        <p>qual seu  pais de origem?</p>
        <input type="text" name="pergunta" id="pergunta">
        <input type="button" value="confirmar nacionalidade" onclick="confirmar()">
        <div id="nacionalidade"> :</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function  confirmar(){
            var pergunta = window.document.querySelector('input#pergunta');
            var nacionalidade = window.document.querySelector('div#nacionalidade');

            if (pergunta == 'Brasil'){
                nacionalidade.innerHTML = ('ola,brasileiro')
            }else{
                nacionalidade.innerHTML =  ('Olae strangeiro')
            }
        }    
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você der um `console.log` na pergunta vai ver que ela retorna o elemento Input inteiro, e de acordo com o seu if, isso cai no "Olae strangeiro'".
Use `pergunta.value` no if.